# Merge Sort Together Two Arrays in Php?

Tags: php, sorting

I'm new to `PHP`, so maybe I'm missing something simple. I have two multidimensional hashes of the form:

```
Array1:
'x' => Array ( 'a' => num1, 'b' => '1' ), 
'y' => Array ( 'a' => num3, 'b' => '3' ), 
'z' => Array ( 'a' => num5, 'b' => '5' ) 

Array2:
'w' => Array ( 'a' => num1, 'b' => '2' ), 
'q' => Array ( 'a' => num3, 'b' => '4' ), 
'r' => Array ( 'a' => num5, 'b' => '6' )
```

Both arrays are sorted by b. All I want to do is merge them together to get a list of the keys sorted by b. This should be a trivial O(n) operation a la merge sort, but I can't find any elegant way of doing this in php with its 50 different sort functions. The result should be:

```
array('x','w','y','q','z','r')
```

I'm fine with using a typical sort at O(nlogn) for this if it's a much shorter solution. I really want to avoid a ton of messy code for the merge/sort function.

Comment: I don't think PHP has a built-in merge+sort. All you can do is merge them and then sort the result.

Comment: @Paulpro Merge sort is `O(n log n)` overall, but the merging of two already sorted arrays that it relies on is `O(n)`. Since my arrays are already sorted, I just need that one step.

Comment: @Eli Right, sorry. I missed the part about your arrays already being sorted by `b`.

Comment: I updated my answer with a `O(n)` solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just union the arrays and then sort the result by `b`:

```
$union = $arr1 + $arr2;
uasort($union, function($a, $b){
    return $a['b'] - $b['b'];
});
$result = array_keys($union);
```

[**Live Demo**](http://ideone.com/q8iUBx)

If you still want a `O(n)` solution this should do it and it's not overly complex, however note that it may be slower unless you are dealing with very large arrays:

```
$result = array(); 
$keys = array_keys($arr2);
$i = 0;
foreach($arr1 as $key => $value){
    while($arr2[$keys[$i]]['b'] < $value['b'])
        $result[] = $keys[$i++];
    $result[] = $key;
}
$result = array_merge($result, array_slice($keys, $i));
```

[**Live Demo**](http://ideone.com/wjouqc)

I have no idea which one of these solutions will achieve the desired result faster in your case. The first one seems more readable though.

Comment: The second one should be faster for any non-trivial number of elements as it is O(n) while the first solution is O(n log n) at the best.

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT

Just noticed you wanted a different result. I misunderstood and thought you wanted to merge the arrays but keep that `b` key in order. Oops! I'll leave this for reference.

---

A nice and easy way:

```
$array1 = array(
    'x' => array ( 'a' => 1, 'b' => '1' ),
    'y' => array ( 'a' => 3, 'b' => '3' ),
    'z' => array ( 'a' => 5, 'b' => '5' )
);

$array2 = array(
    'w' => array ( 'a' => 1, 'b' => '2' ),
    'q' => array ( 'a' => 3, 'b' => '4' ),
    'r' => array ( 'a' => 5, 'b' => '6' ) 
);

$merged = array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
```

Yields:

```
array(6) {
  ["x"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["a"]=>
    int(1)
    ["b"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  ["w"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["a"]=>
    int(1)
    ["b"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  ["y"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["a"]=>
    int(3)
    ["b"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  ["q"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["a"]=>
    int(3)
    ["b"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  ["z"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["a"]=>
    int(5)
    ["b"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  ["r"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["a"]=>
    int(5)
    ["b"]=>
    string(1) "6"
  }
}
```